# Ascii Encryption - PHP

Tags: php, encryption, ascii

I'm trying to convert an input string into ASCII characters "Or any other characters of choice" in PHP. But I could need some assistance.

This is what I've done so far. I had to make this in PHP in this project and I have never really used this language before.

```
<?php

$input = "This is just a test";
print "$input

";

function crypter($input) {

//Variables & Arrays --> Gives each normal character a ascii value
$array = array(
    "a" => "001",
    "b" => "002",
    "c" => "003",
    "d" => "004",
    "e" => "005",
    "f" => "006",
    "g" => "007",
    "h" => "008",
    "i" => "009",
    "j" => "010",
    "k" => "011",
    "l" => "012",
    "m" => "013",
    "n" => "014",
    "o" => "015",
    "p" => "016",
    "q" => "017",
    "r" => "018",
    "s" => "019",
    "t" => "020",
    "u" => "021",
    "v" => "022",
    "w" => "023",
    "x" => "024",
    "y" => "025",
    "z" => "026",
    "æ" => "027",
    "ø" => "028",
    "å" => "029",
    "A" => "031",
    "B" => "032",
    "C" => "033",
    "D" => "034",
    "E" => "035",
    "F" => "036",
    "G" => "037",
    "H" => "038",
    "I" => "039",
    "J" => "040",
    "K" => "041",
    "L" => "042",
    "M" => "043",
    "N" => "044",
    "O" => "045",
    "P" => "046",
    "Q" => "047",
    "R" => "048",
    "S" => "049",
    "T" => "050",
    "U" => "051",
    "W" => "052",
    "V" => "053",
    "X" => "054",
    "Y" => "055",
    "Z" => "056",
    "Æ" => "057",
    "Ø" => "058",
    "Å" => "059",
);

$result = ""; //Empty string variable

//Give the result variable the corresponding ascii character to each input character

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    $c = $input[$i];

    $result += $array[$c];
}

    //Testing - Printing the new result
    print_r($result);
}

crypter($input);

?>
```

Comment: What is your algorithm to the crypter ?

Comment: I just called the function "crypter" It's supposed to take the input and replace each of its containing characters with a given ascii character.

Comment: use what `cabasaki` answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also used `ord()`. Give it a try and let us know if this helps you or not. Adding onto `cabasaki` answer, below is the solution. You might need to tweak it to suit your need.

```
<?php

$input = "This is just a test";
print crypter($input);

function crypter($input)
{
    $result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        $c = ord($input[$i]);

        $result[] = $c;
    }

    return implode('', $result);
}
```

### Output

```
841041051153210511532106117115116329732116101115116
```

Comment: Thank you Samundra! That works really well. But my main idea with this was to learn to choose my own number or character to replace the normal letters. Ascii was just an example. :)

Comment: Do, these, add `" " => "000"` in your `$array` array then change `$result += $array..` to `$result .= $array...` . Change `print_r($result)` to `print $result` you should get the results. The error will occur for every character that is missing from your lookup table.

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem was I used "+=" instead of ".="

Answer (score 2):

Use `ord()` php function to convert characters to ASCII code.

For utf8 inputs have to use `mb_*` functions but without `mb_*`, 's look at manual
on [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php).

Comment: suggesting `ord()` is good one but we don't know yet how he wants to implement the algorithm. So, I think, it's too early to suggest `ord()`.

Comment: Ascii is just an example. How would you go about it if i wanted to replace the characters with something else than ascii?

Comment: I was referring to `chr()` basically. Now, OP has made it clear that ASCII is to be used.